# Sencha Touch Scrolling Issue on IE10 Desktop

Tags: sencha-touch, scrollbar, internet-explorer-10

Unable to make scrolling to work properly on 64bit IE10 Win7.

Main.js

```
Ext.define('ScrollLab.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [

],
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    itemId: 'mainPanel',
    scrollable: true,

    items: [
        {

            xtype: 'container',
            html: 'Sencha Touch 2.3 is the latest version of our industry-leading mobile app framework. In Sencha Touch 2.3 we updated the device APIs to make Apache Cordova a fully supported component in the library, including support (using the latest version of Sencha Command) for the Adobe PhoneGap Build. Touch 2.3 also includes two brand new themes: Cupertino and Mountain View, in addition to several enhancement to existing themes, especially the Blackberry 10 theme. Other enhancements in Touch 2.3 include full support for XMLHTTPRequest Level 2 (XHR2) on devices that support it, and a new ProgressIndicator Component to give users a true indication when uploading. Read more about all the new features of Touch 2.3.',
            width: '100px'
        }

    ]
}
});
```

MainController.js

```
Ext.define('ScrollLab.controller.MainController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires : [
],
config:{
    refs:{
        mainView:      'main'
    },
    control:{
        mainView: {
            activate: 'onMainViewActivate'
        }
    }
},

onMainViewActivate: function(view) {
    "use strict";
    var me=this;

    var container = view;

    if(container.isXType('selectfield')) {
        container = container.down('list');
    }// Add support for selectbuttons

    // Disable default scroll for mobile.
    container.getScrollable().getScroller().setDisabled(true);

    console.log(me.getMainView().element.dom);
    var scrollContainers = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-scroll-view', me.getMainView().element.dom);
    var scrollBars = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-scroll-indicator', me.getMainView().element.dom);

    for(var i=0;i<scrollContainers.length;i++){
        scrollContainers[i].style.overflowY = "scroll";
    }

    for(i=0;i<scrollBars.length;i++) {
        scrollBars[i].style.zIndex = "-1";
    }
    console.log(scrollContainers);
    console.log('Length - ' + scrollContainers.length);

}
});
```

This code enables the scroll but it freeze me on the current view and doesn't let me scroll up/down when content overgrows the screen.

This piece of code works great for Webkit browsers(Chrome, Safari) but doesn't work well on IE10.

Comment: I figured it out. Not a single solution. For different components I had to enable Scroll bars differently. But key thing is using     overflow: scroll and height 100% CSS property at the right place in DOM.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't work for me. It does when I set height to fixed number of px but, the problem is that as the content is created dynamically, I cannot predetermine the size.

Comment: What is your component? can you give more info?

Comment: I am using: {
                 xtype : 'selectfield',
                 store : companiesStore2,
                 name : 'companies',
                 id : 'companiesSelect',
     itemId: 'companySelect',
     valueField : 'companyname',
     displayField : 'companyname',
     style: 'overflow:auto',
     listeners: {
      change: function(field,value) {
       getStats(value)
      }
     } 
              },

Comment: In my case I haven't have a situation to put scrollbar on 'selectfield'. Did you try to play with DOM and CSS on IE's developer mode? Do you have to use 'selectfield'? How about using a 'list' instead? I have scrollbars for list and it doesn't require height in pixel. I believe you can achieve similar result with List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Not a single solution. For different components I had to enable Scroll bars differently. But key thing is using overflow: scroll and height 100% CSS property at the right place in DOM.

Feel free to reach me if you need suggestions.